# Troubles with ImageMagick under XAMPP as a module

Tags: php, module, xampp, typo3, imagick

I have been struggling with installing the ImageMagick module to my XAMPP installation for my Typo3 application. The PHP is 5.4.19, x86, MSVC9. I have tried different versions of IM and IM module, always with different errors on Apache startup including

1. `%1 is not a valid win32 application`
2. `php5.dll is missing`
3. `The procedure entry point MagickGetImageMatte could not be located in the dynamic CORE_RL_wan_.dll`

The last of the errors was with the PHP 5.4 thread safe x86 module and the ImageMagick-6.8.8-7-Q16-x86-dll.exe ImageMagick installation. I then tried to copy the CORE dlls, which the module archive contained, into the ImageMagick folder (replacing the original ones). The error went away, the Apache starts without any errors, the imagick module finally appears in phpinfo, however it says

```
ImageMagick number of supported formats: 0
ImageMagick supported formats no value
```

and in Typo3 the associated functionalities suggest it still is not working properly. What can be done to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

If I was you, I wouldn't try to use the ImageMagick PHP module any more.
This is not really necessary.

I am not even sure if TYPO3 can handle this module at all since I never tried it. 
Since many years I just point the TYPO3 to the binary folder of ImageMagick where all the tools (**convert, composite, identify**) are located.

PHP must be able to call those binaries of course (`exec()` function must be anabled and this folder must be within `open_basedir` if used). It works this way since ever :-)

I recall the very few times I used WAMP environment I had no issues with it either.

Simply download the windows binary of ImageMagick and install it.
Inside the installation folder must be a folder called **/bin**.
The tools needed must be there as exec-files.

Now just set the TYPO3 configuration to point to this folder including the trailing slash.
For windows it must be something like this as I recall.

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['GFX']['im_path'] = 'C:\\programs\\imagemagick\\bin\\';
```

You can use the binaries of GraphicsMagic instead of ImageMagick as well. 
They are easier to find and perform very well.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, +1, however when I deploy to the server the imagick is being supplied as php module so I want to make the environment be the same on both places (also reducing the need for editing particular files while doing it). I'll try GraphicsMagic if it is interchangable.

Comment: Anyway, I am preatty sure that TYPO3 does not support the PHP module but only the binaries as I described. So make sure you can use the binaries on the production server as well and ask for the exec() availability and the path to the binaries. The path is usually /usr/bin/ or /usr/local/bin/.

Comment: On server only module is available and everything regarding pictures works fine.

Comment: I just checked TYPO3 6.1.7, class `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\GraphicalFunctions`, only binaries are used there by calling exec(). No way TYPO3 uses the PHP Imagick module. In fact there is also not a single trace of the class name `Imagick` in the entire core.